# Cython - Checking types of objects

Tags: python, cython

How can I check the types of python objects within cython?

My Cython extension `E` compiles to `E.pyd` within a module `M`.

I am trying to check the type of a python parameter in `class A` of Cython extension `E`.

```
cdef class A:
    def foo(self, bar):
        if bar is A:
            print("ok")
        else
            print("invalid")
```

The trouble is when I go and use the extension from python,

```
from M import E
a = A()
b = A()
a.foo(b)
```

bar is not A, but rather `M.E.A` when I use `type(b)` from Python

I have tried `if bar is M.E.A:` from within Cython but the compiler complains `undeclared name not builtin: M`, since Cython doesn't know about the module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Cython as in Python `is` is the object identity. It is not used for checking type.

- You should write:

  ```
  if isinstance(bar, A):
      ...
  ```

  if you want to check if `bar` is of type `A` or any of its subtype
- or

  ```
  if type(bar) is A:
      ...
  ```

  If you want to check is `bar` is exactly of type `A`.

Alternatively `Cython` provide type checking via:

```
def foo(self, A bar):
```

which allows the user to pass also `None` meaning no object. If you want to exclude `None` write:

```
def foo(self, A bar not None):
```

See [Cython docs on extension types](http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/extension_types.html)